# transaction pending so long with high gas, correct nonce

Tags: blockchain, pending-transactions, raw-transaction

I am making lottery contract, and want to execute set public variable by custom script.
my contract code looks like this.

```
// ...
address[] public applicants;
uint32 numWords = 5;

function setApplicants(address[] memory _applicants) public onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE) {
        require(_applicants.length >= numWords, "applicants should be more than numWords");
        applicants = _applicants;
    }
// ...
```

and my script code looks like this.

```typescript
const lotteryAbi = new ethers.utils.Interface(Lottery__factory.abi);
const providerUrl = getProviderUrl(getChainId()); // custom function

export async function setApplicants(applicants: string[], contractAddress: string, from: string) {
  const txData = lotteryAbi.encodeFunctionData('setApplicants', [applicants]);
  return await makeTx(txData, providerUrl, 25_000_000, '0', from, contractAddress); // custom function. makes raw transaction with high maxFeePerGas, maxPriorityPerGas based on chain gas station
}

// ...sign and send the txData and show transactionHash if mined
```

my contract code works fine in remixIDE online. (with mumbai network)

but when I execute the script, the transaction seems to be stuck.

my custom function works fine because it doesn't make any trouble with other functions.
(so when setApplication transaction stuck, I cancel it by other script with different function.)

I think the problem cause in this code, but don't know why.

```typescript
  const txData = lotteryAbi.encodeFunctionData('setApplicants', [applicants]);
```

Is there a reason why my transaction get stuck with these conditions?

Comment: Can you provide the code of the function `makeTx`? Are you setting the gas limit to  25M? Sometimes transactions with high gas limit take longer to be processed because they are harder to accommodate within a block.

Comment: well, actually my transaction proceeded in gas limit 25M for usage almost 99% in testnet. maybe because I set applicants about 1000 addresses.

However, it has succeeded only twice and has never been successful since then, so instead of increasing the number of transactions, I will lower the number of participants. Anyway, Isn't it okay if the gas cost limit is high but the actual gas cost used is definitely low? @Ismael

Comment: A high gas limit and low gas price may cause delays. Mainnet is much more busy than test nets so I'd suggest to try creating transactions that require less gas. For the gas price start with something more average then you can increase, decrease depending on the time it takes to be confirmed.